# Deleting a row in certain conditions with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to automatically delete rows when the table (shown below) gets a new insert, if certain conditions are met.

When:

- There are rows referring to the same 'field' with the same 'user_id'
- Their 'field', 'display' and 'search' columns are the same

Simply, when the rows would become duplicates (except the 'group_id' column) the non null 'group_id' should be deleted, otherwise a row should be updated or inserted.

Is there a way to set this up in mysql (in spirit of "ON DUPLICATE *do stuff*" combined with unique keys etc.), or do I have to explicitly check for it in php (with multiple queries)?

Additional info:
There should always be a row with NULL 'group_id' for every possible 'field' (there's a limited set, defined elsewhere). On the other hand there might not be one with a non null 'group_id'.

```
CREATE TABLE `Views` (
`user_id` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`db` ENUM('db_a','db_b') NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_swedish_ci',
`field` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_swedish_ci',
`display` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`search` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`group_id` SMALLINT(6) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
UNIQUE INDEX `user_id` (`field`, `db`, `user_id`),
INDEX `Views_ibfk_1` (`user_id`),
INDEX `group_id` (`group_id`),
CONSTRAINT `Views_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `User` (`id`) ON
UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
COLLATE='utf8_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: Could you explain it better: "when all but the group_id columns are the same, the row with not null group_id should be deleted"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to revise your logic. It makes no sense to Insert a row only to delete another row. Why not just update the `Group_ID` field in the duplicate row to what is being inserted? Below is a rough idea of how I would go about it.

*N.b. I haven't done much work with MySQL and cannot get the below to run on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/323ba/19), but based on the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if-statement.html) I can't work out why. Perhaps someone more versed in MySQL can correct me?*

```
SET @User_ID = 1;
SET @db = 'db_a';
SET @Field = 'Field';
SET @Display = 1;
SET @Search = 1;
SET @Group_ID = 1;

IF EXISTS
    (   SELECT  1
        FROM    Views
        WHERE   User_ID = @User_ID
        AND     DB = @DB
        AND     Field = @Field
        AND     Group_ID IS NOT NULL
    ) 
    THEN
        UPDATE  Views
        SET     Group_ID = @Group_ID,
                Display = @Display,
                Search = @Search
        WHERE   User_ID = @User_ID
        AND     DB = @DB
        AND     Field = @Field
        AND     Group_ID IS NOT NULL
ELSE
        INSERT INTO Views (User_ID, DB, Field, Display, Search, Group_ID)
        VALUES (@User_ID, @DB, @Field, @Display, @Search, @Group_ID)
END IF;
```

Alternatively (and my preferred solution), add a Timestamp field to your table and create a view as follows:

```
SELECT  v.User_ID, v.DB, v.Field, v.Display, v.Search, v.Group_ID
FROM    Views v
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  User_ID, DB, Field, MAX(CreatedDate) AS CreatedDate
            FROM    Views
            WHERE   Group_ID IS NOT NULL
            GROUP BY User_ID, DB, Field
        ) MaxView
            ON MaxView.User_ID = v.User_ID
            AND MaxView.DB = v.DB
            AND MaxView.Field = v.Field
            AND MaxView.CreatedDate = v.CreatedDate
WHERE    v.Group_ID IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT  v.User_ID, v.DB, v.Field, v.Display, v.Search, v.Group_ID
FROM    Views v
WHERE   v.Group_ID IS NULL
```

This would allow you to track changes to your data properly, without compromising the need to be able to view unique records.

Comment: It wouldn't work because there will always be a row for each possible 'field' with a NULL group_id. Think of it like this:
The rows with null 'group_id' are the "default" settings for each 'field' (settings are really the 'field', 'display' and 'search' columns). The sets with a group_id (if one exists) are then applied over the default ones for the corresponding group.

The code I'm working on has been inherited and I'm trying to glue a functionality ontop, so what I'm looking for is a good compromise with how easiy it is to set up and how much it makes sense. If that makes sense.

Comment: Sorry I have edited my answer, I forgot to add the clause stipulating `Group_ID IS NOT NULL` in the first solution. With this clause in I don't see why it wouldn't work. Inserting one row with all the same data apart from group ID (where group_ID is not null in either row) and deleting the old row has the same net effect as updating the group id of the old row to the group ID of the new row.

Comment: Only it should update when there is a row with different 'search' and 'display' columns and same 'user_id', 'field' and 'group_id' columns. My question has been poorly worded (I notice I've left out the update thing entirely), but I think I'm getting closer!

Comment: I have edited the queries now to make them work for only unique combinations of `User_ID, Field & DB` where `Group_ID` is not null.

Answer (score 0):

delete group_id  from Views where group_id != 'NUll'

Comment: This is not correct, since NULL is not a value. `WHERE group_id IS NOT NULL` would be correct but I don't know if a solution here since I haven't read the question yet.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very good to understand, so I'm not sure this is what you want:

```
DELETE FROM Views WHERE # delete from the table views
  group_id IS NOT NULL AND  # first condition delete only rows with not null group_id
  (SELECT count(*) as tot FROM Views GROUP BY group_id) = 1 # second condition count the difference in group id
```

If that's not what you want, please update your question with more details...